# The program shows erroe in line 37 where I am trying to display a charcater but it say's it's an integer. So, it does not display line 37 and skips it

Tags: c, char, structure

/*  > Error shown: main.c:37:23: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
printf("Name is: %s\n",s[x].n[20]); */

```
        #include<stdio.h>
            struct student
            {
                int roll;
                char n[20];
                float per;
            }`enter code here`
            main()
            {
                int n;
                printf("Enter number of students");
                scanf("%d",&n);
                struct student s[n];
                for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                {
                printf("Roll number:\n");
                scanf("%d",&s[i].roll);
                printf("Name:\n");
                scanf("%s",&s[i].n[20]);
                printf("Percentage:\n");
                scanf("%f",&s[i].per);
                }
              int x;
              printf("Student you want to acess:\n");
              scanf("%d",&x);
               if(x<=n){
                printf("The information of the stuent is as follows:\n");
                printf("Roll no is: %d\n",s[x].roll);
                printf("Name is: %s\n",s[x].n[20]);     //does not print idk why
                printf("Percentage is: %f\n",s[x].per);
               }
               else if(x>n)
               {
               printf("Error:Input no valid!");
               }
            }
```

Comment: `printf("Name is: %s\n",s[x].n[20]);` -> `printf("Name is: %s\n",s[x].n);`

Comment: `scanf("%s",&s[i].n[20]);` -> `scanf("%s",s[i].n);`

Comment: `if(x<=n)` -> `if(x<n && x>0)`

Answer (score 1):

`printf("Name is: %s\n",s[x].n[20]);` is attempting to print, as a *string*, the `char` at `s[x].n[20]`, which is outside that array.

To print `s[x].n` as a *string*, use `printf("Name is: %s\n",s[x].n);`.

Tip: enable all compiler warnings to save time.

Other problems exist in code too.